# Connect Android App on a PC-based database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm creating an Android App that would have to access a database on my PC.  I know how to program in Java and access a MySQL on my PC using JDBC ODBC.  Could anyone lead me to the right place?

Answer (score 1):

android don't support jdbc.

why don't you make a application-server?

the architecture is this.
Android <<--(using REST/JSON)-->>Application-Server(including JDBC or ODBC) <<-->> Database

using json or rest is good to reduce data traffic.
and generally the application server is faster than Android device.

Comment: or the database could be local to the application/device.  even if u need to make updates you can just push out a new version of the app.  a remote database would be more for real time updates (but of course has the downfall of needing to be managed)